# recover from non-english keyboard layout at boot?

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard-layout

It seems that the system comes up with hebrew keyboard layout. Which - AFAIK - has no small latin letters. And it asks for disk password. Which contains small latin letters.

In grub the layout is english, so I can enter whatever I need. I can even go to command line using "break" as a boot parameter. But I have no idea how to enter a command in the command line, as I have only hebrew letters, latin capitals, and punctuation.

How to recover from this situation?

Is there a way to make sure that password entry is always using english layout?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to boot with installer, "try Ubuntu live", and add a password to the disk which works with hebrew keyboard layout.